# Sharepoint XSLT date formula

Tags: sharepoint, date, xslt

Hi I am working on a Sharepoint list and am totally lost on how they calculate dates.  I got a column pulling a date from a datasource.  What I need is to just add a day to the date pulled.

e.g the date of the day after the given date.  Can I do this using the formula?

The code in the XSLT at the moment is

```
<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@Expiry" />
```

Comment: What type of content does the Expiry attribute have?

Comment: just a date in dd/mm/yyyy format

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is easier to add a calculated column to the list, and just use that.

Answer (score 0):

Because your XSLT processor is an XSLT 1.0 processor, you could use EXSLT [`date:add()`](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/add/index.html) function. There is a pure XSLT named template implementation by [Jeni Tennison](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/add/date.add.template.xsl)

Answer (score 0):

You can format the datetime using the "ddwrt" namespace and leveraging the "FormatDate" function in your XSL. I put together a short writeup if anyone is interested http://labs.steveottenad.com/sharepoint-2010-xslt-date-formatting/ here is a great writeup on the different formats you can feed the formatdate function to get the formatting you need - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshuag/archive/2009/03/25/custom-date-formats-in-sharepoint-xsl.aspx - near the bottom of the page.